# Bootstrap - section and div positioning

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using a Bootstrap template to build a website. I have 2 questions I am struggling to solve:

1) When I put my HTML code into a < section >, automatically some sort of top margin/padding is applied to the section. There is no css code affecting the section.
I can't seem to be able to control how much padding/margin is applied at the top/bottom.

Would anyone know if this is normal and how can I control amount of spacing?

2) If I don't use the section but just the div to separate each portion of my code the text goes right at the top of my page with no spacing at all. I tried using some css but failed at any attempt. This my most recent and basic attempt (also failing)

```
.q2 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Thanks for any help - I have tried adding and removing section, using the bootstrap grid, a table but it all still gets either squashed together (if I don't use sections) or way too far apart (if I use sections).

HTML code:

```
<section>
  <div class="container">
  <form action="sqlQuery.php" method="post" name="foundationsurvey">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 text-center pb-3">
        <label for="Q1">Q1</label>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-left ml-4">
          <input type="radio" id="dry" required> <label for="dry"> Dry </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-left ml-4">
          <input type="radio" id="normal" required> <label for="normal"> Normal</label>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>

    <!--Q2-->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <label for="Q2">Q2</label>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" name="product1" placeholder="Brand, Product Name" required>
            </div>
              <div class="col">
                <input type="text" name="product2" placeholder="Brand, Product Name" required>
              </div>
         </div>
        </div>
  </section>
    </header>
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the HTML that goes along with the q2 class?

Comment: Added now, thank you!

Comment: I tried manipulate your problem but seem alright from my end? Anywhere we can view the full page preview?

Comment: @Vincent1989 You mean the css? Do you not get funny spacing using the section element?

Comment: To clarify - I found a way to add the padding around the section using this  section {
  padding: 100px 0; }

.section-heading {
  margin-top: 0; } 

but I still can't find a way to bring the div down and make it positioned in relation to the previous div element

Comment: I also wasn't able to reproduce the strange spacing for the top/bottom margins with bootstrap 3 or 4.

Comment: must have done something I am not aware of with my css :-(
however section was only something I used to resolve the problem of the div being up at the top of my page.

Does anyone know at all how can I get the div to be positioned 50px below the nav bar for example?

Comment: I suspect there must be some other css that you are using that's causing the layout issue, as we don't seem to produce the error that you mentioned

Comment: thank you Both, I'll go through the whole template again to see what is making my section behave bizzarly.

If anyone knows at all how can I set the div at a specified distance from previous div/element I would really thank you a lot!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the q2 class applied?
try the following:

```
... <div class="container q2"> ...
```

all styles work:

```
section {
    margin-top: 150px;
}
.q2 {
    /* position: relative; */
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: this worked! thanks!!!!! (For reference, I didn't specify position. I only entered margin-top for .q2)

Comment: position is commented for example, all right! I was glad to help you)